# Looping through a collection with an array - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, loops, laravel-blade

I have a collection which I have extracted from the database using the findMany method in eloquent.
When I *dd* the collection it looks like the attached image. And then I am trying to *(in my blade)* loop through each item in the array such that I am able to print each of the values in the actual records.

```
$question = Question::whereIn('id', [23,25])->get();
```

Then in my blade I am trying to do:

```
@foreach ($question as $row => $innerArray)
    @foreach ($innerArray as $innerRow => $value)
        {{$value->question}} //I was expecting "What is your favourite food" here
        @foreach ($value->option as $choice)
            <li>{{$choice}}</li> //I was expecting the list of the options here
        @endforeach 
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't `{{$value->question}} ` be {{$value['question']}} since is an array and not an object property ? And same for  `@foreach ($value->option as $choice)` with `$value['options']` with and 's'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All multi-result sets returned by Eloquent are instances of the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` object, including results retrieved via the get method or accessed via a relationship. The Eloquent collection object extends the Laravel [base collection](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections), so it naturally inherits dozens of methods used to fluently work with the underlying array of Eloquent models.

All collections also serve as iterators, allowing you to loop over them as if they were simple PHP arrays:

```
$questions = Question::whereIn('id', [23, 25, ..])->get();

foreach ($questions as $question) {
    echo $question->title; // What is your favourite food
    echo $question->name; // food

    foreach ($question->options as $option) {
         echo $option; // Pizza
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually had this and it didn't work. So I thought what I had was wrong, turns out it was something else that was breaking it. Just to add for the options, i needed to json_decode it as this is an array stored as a string so effectively hads to use @foreach (json_decode($question->options) as $option)

Comment: Right, since what you have there is a string then you have to decode it. However, Laravel has something more elegant than this. Read a little about [Attribute Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)

Comment: Would it be possible to conduct the loop without get() method? I am using `yajra/laravel-datatables` and wanted to keep the query as eloquent builder not collection instance.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is this:

```
@foreach ($question as $q)
    {{ $q->question }} //I was expecting "What is your favourite food" here
     @foreach ($q->options as $choice)
         <li>{{$choice}}</li> //I was expecting the list of the options here
     @endforeach 
@endforeach
```